# Utility to FORCE a Windows desktop to lock after <x> minutes of inactivity (screensaver unreliable)

Tags: windows-7, windows, screensaver

Title says it all, it seems my Windows 7 workstation doesn't always respect the screensaver settings, is there a secondary utility that would be able to forcefully lock the workstation after a certain amount of inactivity?

Comment: Unless you computer is broken in some weird way, you most likely just have a device keeping your computer awake. Probably a USB peripheral.  Why not solve that problem instead of asking for a utility that does this (which is generally an unaccepted practice for SU)?  [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/174452).

Comment: To lock the screen automatically, check the On resume option and set the Wait option to an appropriate number of minutes. The default, one minute, is decidedly too short.